# Can not disable ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have made a simple Web Form where I try to get rid of the ViewState. When I run it and press Go the label gets the value of whatever I put in the texbox. So far all good. But the textbox maintains the value I filled in. As far as I understand it this is done by the ViewState mechanism. What do I miss?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="SportsPlay.Sida1" ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnableViewState="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" enableviewstate="false">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTest" ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnGo" Text="Go" OnCommand="btnGo_Command" />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblResult"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script runat="server" language="C#">
    void btnGo_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        lblResult.Text =txtTest.Text ;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ViewState manages the information of the current page. It is utilized by the HTML pages by ASP.NET applications to maintain the state of the web form controls. By this you can save a lot of coding by maintaining the ViewState of the objects in your Web Form.

**You do not need ViewState in the following situations:**

1. The control is repopulated on every postback. If you ignore old data, and if you repopulate the server control each time the page is refreshed then you do not need ViewState.
2. When you complete a web page, review the controls in the page and consider what information is being passed in the view state and whether you really need all that information to be maintained. To optimize web page size, consider disabling view state in these cases.
3. The control is an input control and it changes only from user actions.
4. The control never changes.

**By default, ViewState is enabled for all server controls. ViewState can be enabled and disabled in any of the following ways:**

- Control Level
- Page Level
- Application Level
- Machine Level

**To disable ViewState**

To disable ViewState for a single control on a page, set the EnableViewState property of the control to false, as in the following:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
```

**To disable ViewState for a page**

To disable ViewState for a single page, set the EnableViewState attribute in the @ Page directive to false, as in the following:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableViewState="false" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="URLRouting.aspx.cs" Inherits="URL_Rewriting" %>
```

To disable a page's View State, add the code below in the Page class of the page.

```
public void DisableViewState()
{
    this.Init += new EventHandler(Page_Init);
}

private void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.EnableViewState = false;
}
```

**To disable ViewState for a specific application**

To disable ViewState for a specific application, use the following element in the Web.config file of the application:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages enableViewState="false" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**To disable ViewState for all applications on a Web server**

To disable ViewState for all applications on a Web server, configure the  element in the Machine.config file as follows:

```
<Machine.config >
    <system.web>
       <pages enableViewState="true" />           
    </system.web>
 </Machine.config>
```

Comment: So why does the textbox show the text after postback? I have tried most of what you suggest with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the previous answer you can explicitly clear it on click TextBox1.Text = ""; Or Redirect to the same page should clear everything out.

Comment: But why is the textbox filled after postback?

Comment: because it looks like you are setting it on click/postback:  lblResult.Text =txtTest.Text ;

Comment: I am setting the label (lblResult), not the textbox (txtTest). I set the label just to confirm that a postback has occurred. What I understand when I read up on ViewState is that the textbox should not maintain its value when EnableViewState="false". I have tried to disable it in the textbox, in the form and on the project level too with the same result.

Comment: https://codewala.net/2011/02/07/why-textbox-persists-data-during-postback-even-if-view-state-set-to-off/